# How to add additional partitions to Windows under bootcamp

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition

I have a MBP on which running OS X 10.8.4. Recently using bootcamp I installed Windows 7 on it to use some windows specific software. I wanted to have 3 different partitions in windows, where OS and apps are installed on 1 and my data remains on other 2.

However, due to some restrictions with bootcamp, I wasn't able to create partitions before installing windows (bootcamp require single partition in Mac OS X to setup windows).

Then, I installed windows first and tried to create partition via Disk Utility and then lost my windows installation. Later based on a [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4144252?start=30&tstart=0) on apple discussions, I was able to repair boot partition for windows and get it up, but its no longer showing my mac hd and other 2 partition which I created.

So wondering, if there is any safe way to make those 2 partitions available in my windows OS along with HFS+ drive, which was being shown earlier but later no longer accessible in windows. (I even tried re-installing bootcamp drivers with no luck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely related to your partitioning method. When you edit a Windows 7 partition with Disk Utility it will let you do it but it doesnt work very well and will likely cause a lot of problems.

Your best option would be to back up your partitions data to another drive and then re-create the bootcamp partition using BootCamp assistant as you did before. But when it comes to partitioning the Windows 7 Partitions only use Windows disk management tool (Can be found by right clicking on computer and going to Manage->Storage->Disk Management.

Windows 7 for adjusting Windows 7 partition (NTFS)
Disk Utility for adjust any OSX (HFS partitions)

Comment: So if there isn't any other way except re-installing windows? I want to avoid this step, given that it takes lots of time to install and configure my development environment in windows. I earlier tried to find option to use my existing PC HDD image to restore using cloning method but found that it was also not possible. So took hard route of re-creating partitions in Mac OS X (as bootcamp require it to be single partition).

Comment: Okay so I don't think there is going to be any 'safe' method. But I can give you a few options to try. Depending on your need for your machines specs and Dev requirements it might be worth installing vmware fusion. It is b possible to access Bootcamp partitions from the new versions.

Comment: Another option might be to use deploy studio to capture your ntfs drive and deploy it out again with an osx partition also. You could use Windows 7 backup tools to create a backup.  Rebuild your machine with a clean win7 image and restore your backup but I can't be sure this would resolve your issue. I personally would give fusion a go first as there is a free trial. Hope this gives you a few options to think about.

Comment: Okay, I will look into Fusion option. Though, if there would have been an safest way to add my 2 existing NTFS partitions (which I had created via Disk utility) to Windows as well access mac drive as before.  If you think that during boot repair using GPT (as per that apple post) there could be any option to add more partitions to windows?

Comment: Not through disk utility. Using Windows tools you could.  But using disk utility for osx it will get messy. Disk utility is unable to make changes to ntfs partitions